# HTML input number custom validation message

Tags: html, validation, input, asp.net-mvc-5

i've stumbled upon a problem and i can't find the proper solution.

```
<input type="number" class="span8" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('@Resources.Employee.EmploymentTimeRequired')" data-name="EmploymentTime" min="0" max="40" />/40<
```

I have the following code and i would like to get two different validation messages for it:
one when the field is empty and the second one if the number entered exceeds the max or min values. Right now i have only one validation message. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

this should work
HTML code

```
<input type="number" class="span8" onchange="validate(this.id)" id="input1"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT code

```
function validate(id){
 var  inputval = document.getElementById(id).value;
 var length = inputval.length;
 if(length==0){
 alert("empty");
 }else if(length<MIN){
  //MIN is your minimum number of charecter
  alert("minimum " + MIN + " charecter are required ");
 }else if(length>MAX){
   //MAX is your maximum number of charecter
  alert("maximum " + MAX + " charecter are required ");
 }

}
```

EDIT:
add a **span** tag after **input** tag width **id** attribute

now HTML WOULD be

```
<input type="number" class="span8" onchange="validate(this.id)" id="input1"/><span id="errorinput1"></span>
```

and JAVASCRIPT WOULD be

```
function validate(id){
var  inputval = document.getElementById(id).value;
var length = inputval.length;
var error = document.getElementById("errorinput1");
if(length==0){
error.innerHTML="EMPTY";
}else if(length<MIN){
//MIN is your minimum number of charecter
error.innerHTML="minimum " + MIN + " charecter are required ";
}else if(length>MAX){
 //MAX is your maximum number of charecter
 error.innerHTML="maximum " + MAX + " charecter are required ");
}

}
```